# Generated classes cannot find model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, t4

I feel like I'm missing something pretty simple... I just got started using a Database-first Entity Framework project and I've been having issues getting the generated classes to work. I have my diagram set up and the database is correct, but the generated EDMX is having issues.

**PaymentData.cs (generated)**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Project.Web.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class PaymentData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The "Account" model can't be found even though Account.edmx is in the same folder, with the same namespace, and was generated by Entity Framework. So why can't this file (which was generated) find the model (which was ALSO generated)? I've done code-first before and never had this problem, so it's driving me crazy!

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding? It can be an issue sometimes..

Comment: I did not, but that fixed it. Seems like the model was LONG outdated and I didn't even bother to check. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the model/class in EDMX and rebuild it again.

Comment: You'd think I would have thought of that... but of course, I didn't. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class name is Account Not Accounts